# How to generate relativistic pseudo-potential using Vanderbilt USPP that captures spin-orbit coupling?

Tags: density-functional-theory, pseudopotentials, relativistic, spin-orbit-coupling

I have used Vanderbilt USPP for generating a pseudopotential that does not include the spin-orbit term.

But I want to have the spin-orbit coupling term included in the pseudopotential, to do research on a van der Waal (VDW) hetero-structure of 2D materials.

How do I use Vanderbilt USPP to generate a pseudopotential including spin-orbit coupling? I'm working on the Mo atom.

Comment: Generating your own Pseudos and achieving transferrable results is a difficult task in my opinion. If you've generated your own pseudopotentials, including spin-orbit coupling might not be difficult after all. Pseudos themselves are a very broad area and one could spend months or even a year studying how they work and how to generate a 'good' pseudo.

Answer (score 3):

The spin-orbit effect is something that your code has to be able to do, it is not a property of the pseudopotential.

Here you can find other discussions about it:

- [How to incorporate the effect of spin-orbit coupling in electronic structure calculation](https://materials.stackexchange.com/questions/308/how-to-incorporate-the-effect-of-spin-orbit-coupling-in-electronic-structure-cal)
- [Spin–orbit interaction with DFT](https://materials.stackexchange.com/questions/1144/spin-orbit-interaction-with-dft)